# How to check whether URL only contains the domain using javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, url

How can I check whether url only contains the domain in javascript?

```
let s = 'some url string';
```

that must be working like below.

```
https://google.com/ --> true
https://docs.google.com/ --> true

https://google.com/blabla  --> false
https://google.com/blabla/ ---> false
https://docs.google.com/blabla/ ---> false
```

Comment: Use Window.location.href   there u will get the full url as  array (may be ) then u can split it and check what u need to check

Comment: can you provide me the example?

Comment: `"http://google.com".includes("google") // true`

Comment: no, any url not the google.com

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a good regular expression to match a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809401/what-is-a-good-regular-expression-to-match-a-url)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the global `URL`:

```
const url = new URL('', 'https://google.com/blabla ');
console.log(url.hostname); // "google.com"
console.log(url.pathname); // "/blabla"
```

You can check `url.pathname`, and if there is no pathname, it will return `/`.

```
const url = new URL('', 'https://google.com ');
console.log(url.hostname); // "google.com"
console.log(url.pathname); // "/"
```

Comment: Note that `URL` is not supported by internet explorer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use regex to check URLs content. The `/^https?:\/\/[^\/?]+\/$/g` match any URL that start with `http` and end with domain suffix and `/`

```
var url = 'https://google.com/';
/^https?:\/\/[^\/?]+\/$/g.test(url) // true
```

```js
function testURL(url){
  return /^https?:\/\/[^\/?]+\/$/g.test(url);
}
console.log(testURL('https://google.com/'));
console.log(testURL('https://docs.google.com/'));
console.log(testURL('https://google.com/blabla'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can use `Window.location` to get all these details

Ex: for this question:

```
window.location.hostname  ==>> // "stackoverflow.com"

window.location.pathname == >> ///questions/53249750/how-to-check-whether-url-only-contains-the-domain-in-js

window.location.href == >>
"https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53249750/how-to-check-whether-url-only- 
 contains-the-domain-in-js"
```

**You can check for pathName and do your thing:**

```
if (window.location.pathname === "" || window.location.pathname === "/") {
   return true
}
```

Comment: Note this assumes that the string OP wants to check is based on current location rather than some variable input